# Android relative layout, positioning something in the middle of 2 views

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have 2 ImageButtons and a Seerkbar inside a relative layout and I am trying to position them so that :

1) first imageButton is on the left, it's left side and the parent's left side align.

2) second imageButton is on the right, it's right side and the parent's right side align.

3) the Seekbar is in the middle, and it covers all of the remaining space.

It should look something like this:

[image]
I tried this:

```
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/image_1"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                 android:src="@drawable/image_1"/>

    <SeekBar android:id="@+id/seek_bar"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image_1"
             android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/image_2"
             android:max="95"/>

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/image_2"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                 android:src="@drawable/image_2"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This works fine on my intellij device preview, BUT fails to compile because of the line:

```
          android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/image_2"
```

as I am using the id/image_2 before declaring it. Is there a solution to this ?

Comment: thanks, I didn't even think that I should declare with + on the first occurance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TRY THIS....


<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/image_1"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                     android:src="@drawable/image_1"/>

        <SeekBar android:id="@+id/seek_bar"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_1"
                 android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/image_2"
                 />

        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/image_2"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                     android:src="@drawable/image_2"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to put `+` sign before `id` like this:

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_1"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/image_2"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend in the `RelativeLayout` to reference two components such as `toRightOf` and `toLeftOf`. Always try to reference each to only one. In your case you can also use `LinearLayout` with weights for a uniformed distribution for the chils as the following

```
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/image_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seek_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:max="95" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/image_2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: how would you say to the second image button to stay on the right  in a linearlayout ?

Comment: @sakiskaliakoudas using the attribute `weight`

Comment: @sakiskaliakoudas It enforce the children of the layout to be distributed equally along the width of the parent according to the given weight

Comment: Yes, I know weight. Your declaration is a bit wrong though, yours would cause the imagebuttons to stretch. Those buttons have specific dimensions. But if you remove the weight from the image buttons and leave it on the seekbar it just might work

Comment: @sakiskaliakoudas you can use the trick of `weight=0` for the item that you need to take its proper size at the begining then give the rest `weight=1` to distribute themselves allover the rest empty space

Comment: Yes, that's what I had in mind. good one

Comment: @sakiskaliakoudas I hope you find it useful for you. Happy coding

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74346/discussion-between-tamawy-and-sakis-kaliakoudas).

Answer (score 0):

This would help you deal with different resolution, give it a try
i have put the `imageview` instead of `seekbar` lol

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="100"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="#FFF"
android:layout_margin="1dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="40"
    android:background="#aef"
    android:layout_margin="4dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:background="#984"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dip"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:background="#fec"
    android:layout_margin="4dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:background="#594"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="40"
    android:background="#9ef"
    android:layout_margin="4dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:background="#994"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]